# In a Facebook fan page post, what happen to replies underneath after I delete my comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, comments, delete

Assume I made a comment to a post on a Facebook fan page (which is public) not owned by me, then a few other people (none of them are the owner of the page) replied, so the replies went under my comment. After that I would like to delete my comment. What will happen to the replies underneath? Will they (A) be deleted as well, or (B) become direct comments to the post? Or are there any other possibilities (like I am not allowed to delete the comment at all)?

Answer (score 3):

If you delete a comment, it deletes all replies to that comment.